# zf2 multiple forms on one page

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework, zend-framework2

So, i'm learning Zend Framework 2 at the moment and i'm struggling at a point.

Scenario: I have one View wich displays a Question. For this Question, i have 3 different forms:

- form 1: Update the Status of the Question (unanswered, answered etc.)
- form 2: Set the responsible employee of this Question.
- form 3: leave a comment on this Question.

I display all the forms through a single Action and on a single View. I'd like to have all the forms on the same Page because it's just more user-friendly.

Question: How should i do all the form processing? Should this be done all in the same Action (of course, persiting Data is on the Service Layer) and just ask which Forms the User sent, or should i create 3 different Actions - one for each Form?

Comment: How is your data structured?  Does each form represent a different table or do they each update specific columns in the same table?

Comment: @jcropp Each form represents a different table. I have a Comment, Status and Employee table and the Question table just has references to each Record.